# How to add combobox from source code along with drag and drop GUI Java NetBean

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, combobox

I'm starting using java with NetBeans IDE. I'm using drag and dop GUI, it's so easy to use, but I got a problem. I'm writing this code at the contructor:

```
JComboBox combobox=new JComboBox();
combobox.addItem("Apple");
combobox.addItem("Banana");

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
    combobox.addItem(i);
}
```

just right above `initComponents();` hoping that my new combobox will shown when I run the project, but it doesn't. Did I do something wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello? If anything is unclear about my answer, please comment to the answer or below to let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are creating a JComboBox, and yes, you are adding items to it (numeric and int -- that's a problem, but that's a discussion for another day), but no, you're not showing any code where you add this newly created JComboBox to a component that is displayed in the GUI. To display a component in a Swing GUI, it must be created **and added to a component that is ultimately displayed in a top-level window, in the "GUI"**.

So this begs the question, how do you add your created JComboBox to your GUI that you've created with drag and drop code? One way: you could add it to say a JPanel that's already in your GUI, but you will need to do this after initializing components, usually this means *after* the constructor calls `initComponents()`, and you'll also need to make sure that this JPanel uses a layout manager that makes it easy for it to accept new components (this means *most* of the layout managers except NetBean's default layout, GroupLayout).

There are other issues, such as whether or not the container holding your JComboBox is large enough to display it, but the **best** suggestion that I can give is for you to go through the Swing tutorials, and hit especially hard the layout manager section. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).